# How to run system command on heroku server?

Tags: heroku

I am using OGR2OGR for converting geojson file into dxf format.
It is working on local server but on heroku server it is not working.
Find code which is using  for genrating file:

```
          str2 = {
            "type":"FeatureCollection",
            "features":[
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@substation]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@feeder]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@form3]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@pdt_array]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@edt_array]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@composite_array]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@al_array]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@tp_array]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[@ot_array]}},
                 {"type":"Feature","properties":{"color":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[@lt_array,@ht_array,@consumer_array]}}
               ]}

   path = "#{Rails.root}/public/data.geojson"
   File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
     f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(str2))
   end
   system("ogr2ogr -f DXF #{Rails.root}/public/delhiii.dxf  #{Rails.root}/public/data.geojson")
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not let you save files directly to their filesystem. There is a thing called [Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) but it is not reliable. I would suggest using S3 for saving files.

Also, Heroku will not let you install external libraries (ogr2ogr). Sometimes you can get gems with binaries (like [wkhtmltopdf-binary gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary/versions/0.9.9.3)) but I can not find such solution for ogr2ogr.